# Django ModelAdmin Fieldset within fieldset

Tags: python, django

What I've been asked create is an admin page with the following layout:

- Fieldset 1 name

  - Section 1 name

    - field 1
    - field 2
- Fieldset 2 name

  - Section 2 name

    - field 3

and so on.

I can create the fieldsets with ModelAdmin.fieldsets obviously, but its the inner grouping or "Sections" that I'm having difficulty with. The fields to display all belong to the same model, so I can't achieve this with Inlines (or at least I believe I can't).

I'm pretty sure the only way to achieve what I want is to create a custom template and to by pass Django's default loveliness but I'd ideally like to extend the Django Admin because this Fieldset -> Section -> fields layout will be required for several models and I don't want to have to manually generate forms & templates for each model, if I can help it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to achieve the above layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you're out of luck, the Django admin [does not support nested fieldsets](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10590) and has no way to output other structural tags, except by customising the templates.

You can have a look at:
http://django-betterforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html

It supports nested fieldsets, so this code will help you when you are customising your admin templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a page something like this :

[image]

Then you can add following to your admin file :

```
from django.contrib import admin

class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('url', 'title', 'content', 'sites')
        }),
        ('Advanced options', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('registration_required', 'template_name'),
        }),
    )
```

And for more details you can check this [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Django still doesn't support nested fieldsets (April 2022).

Instead, I had to go through and organize my fieldsets into tuples

```
('Water Conveyance', {
    'classes': ('collapse',),
    'fields': (('spillway_gate', 'bypass_valve'), ('trash_exclusion', 'intake_gate', 'intake_passage', 'shutoff_valve'), ('cone', 'isolation'))
}),
```

And then set `verbose_name` on all my field definitions

```
spillway_gate = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=Key.choices, default=Key.default, verbose_name="Bypass - Spillway Gate")
bypass_valve = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=Key.choices, default=Key.default, verbose_name="Bypass - Bypass Valve")
```

Not as pretty, but it works

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkzfH.png)